# If God created the human "in His image", doesn't that mean that God is evil and full of faults?

Tags: bible

This is a sincere question.

If "in His image" means "like God in behaviour/spirit/mindset", and so many humans (most/all of them, I would say) are so incredibly vile/evil, what does that say about God? And this is not just an opinion; the Bible is absolutely full of mentions of evil people doing evil things. But they were still created in His image?

This is one of many things which I think about a lot but never know how I can get answered. If I ask any non-religious person, I will just get jokes/nonsense as a reply. If I ask a religious/Christian person, I'm likely to get something along the lines of "it's the Devil's fault" or "God acts in mysterious ways, too complicated for us mere mortals to understand".

Nevertheless, I'm trying to understand, because things like this bother me. I *want* it to make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We are different to other sites and we try to avoid questions that will attract opinion-based answers.  Please take our Tour to see how your question could be improved: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It's odd that you say religious people just give you stock answers when the answer is literally right there in the same book where God makes man in His image. Adam and Eve were created "very good" and without fault, and they decided to turn away from God, anyway, causing the Fall.

Comment: @jaredad7 Yes, but God created them?

Comment: Yes, He did. I don't understand where the problem lies. God made them able to make moral choices, as curiousdannii says in their answer. They made the wrong moral choice. This caused the rest of us to inherit original sin. God didn't make them evil from the beginning. They chose evil (as do we, though it is harder for us to choose good than it was for them) all on their own

Comment: @jaredad7 My basic point is that God, after all, created Adam. He, in turn, was bound by His rules, just like the artificial intelligence in a video game character is to the programming of the authors of the game, even if it appears as if they have a "free will".

Comment: If your premise is that men don't have free will, then that's your problem, and your question should be "why do Christians believe that men have free will?" And this honestly is probably more of a philosophy topic anyway, at that point.

Comment: If you want to know how different Christian denominations deal with "human nature" and Original Sin that's OK.  But as it stands, this is a general philosophy question.  God is the creator of the universe accessible to everyone.  Man being made in His image is a concept in all Abrahamic religions.  You need to narrow down to asking specifically about Christian doctrine for the purposes of this site

Answer (score 1):

It's debated what exactly it means for humanity to be made "in God's image", but I think it includes being made with the capacity to make real and moral choices. An animal may be mean and vicious, but we don't ascribe moral culpability to it, and we don't call it "evil". Being made in God's image includes both the potential to follow him in righteousness, but also the possibility of spurning God, choosing to hate rather than love, and all other kinds of evil. But being made in God's image also means the possibility of being reconciled back to God, as we were created to be in right relationship with him.

Answer (score 1):

Adam and Eve were created in righteousness, but of their own free will chose to disobey God. They fell. The image of God was marred. They passed this sin nature onto their offspring, and by extension, all of humanity, excepting Jesus (and according to Catholics, in a special sense, Mary).

Thus we are like a painting that a vandal has slashed and splashed with paint.

The important point is that God did not sin. His image has not been marred. Jesus is that image:

> Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every creature
> (Colossians 15:1)